# Using extend with union types to type events. Error: Argument of type X is not assignable to parameter of type Y

Tags: typescript

This is quite a simple typescript/typings problem, but I can't figure it out:

I have an event coming through to a handler function. The event has some properties that are common to all events, and will also have some properties particular to different events. I'm trying to type the events by extending an interface of common properties, but I keep getting errors. Simple js/ts:

```js
interface BaseEventProps {
  baseProp1: string;
}

interface ExtendedEvent1 extends BaseEventProps {
  extendedProp1: string;
}

interface ExtendedEvent2 extends BaseEventProps {
  extendedProp2: string;
}

type Either = ExtendedEvent1 | ExtendedEvent2;

function takeExtendedEvent1(arg: ExtendedEvent1) {
  console.log(arg);
}

function takeExtendedEvent2(arg: ExtendedEvent2) {
  console.log(arg);
}

function handlerFunction(arg: Either) {
  takeExtendedEvent1(arg); // Throws the error below
  takeExtendedEvent2(arg); // Throws the error below
}
```

The error:

```
Argument of type 'Either' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ExtendedEvent1'.
  Property 'extendedProp1' is missing in type 'ExtendedEvent2' but required in type 'ExtendedEvent1'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: `arg` can be Event1 or Event2, but you are giving it to a function that only expects Event1. What if it is Event2? Then your function might break.

Comment: Oh I see, I need to typeguard before I pass the argument in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Credit @caTS - My typescript was fine. The problem was in my js. I just needed to typeguard before passing the args:

```js
function handlerFunction(arg: Either) {
  if ("extendedProp1" in arg) {
    takeExtendedEvent1(arg); // Throws the error below
  }
  if ("extendedProp2" in arg) {
    takeExtendedEvent2(arg); // Throws the error below
  }
}
```